# NPM module to convert image to pencil sketch

Tags: node.js, imagick

I want to convert an image to pencil sketch using nodejs. I checked imagemagick npm and not able to find sketchImage method that is available with imagick php.

I tried jimp npm and manually applied invert, gaussian but the gaussian is too slow and need to dodge again.

I want to know is there any npm module that provides method like sketchImage or any other alternative series of effects that i can use to achieve the desired effect. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest is just spawn a child process that calls that imagemagick program. Otherwise you can extend an existing Node image module to call that C API.